# url errors in beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to obtain data-PID and price from Craigslist using beautifulsoup. I have written a separate code which gives me the file CLallsites.txt. In this code I am trying to grab each of those sites from the txt file and get the PIDs of all entries in the first 10 pages. My code is:

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup       
  from urllib2 import urlopen 
  readfile = open("CLallsites.txt")
  product = "mcy"
  while 1:
    u = ""
    count = 0
    line = readfile.readline()
    commaposition = line.find(',')
    site = line[0:commaposition]
    location = line[commaposition+1:]
    site_filename = location + '.txt'
    f = open(site_filename, "a")
    while (count < 10):
       sitenow = site + "\\" + product + "\\" + str(u)
       html = urlopen(str(sitenow))                      
       soup = BeautifulSoup(html)                
       postings = soup('p',{"class":"row"})
       for post in postings:
            y = post['data-pid']
            print y
       count = count +1
       index = count*100
       u = "index" + str(index) + ".html"
    if not line:
        break
    pass
```

My CLallsites.txt looks like this:

craiglist site, location (Stackoverflow does not allow posting with cragslist links so I cannot show the text, I could try to attach the text file if that helps.)

when I run the code I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "reading.py", line 16, in 
    html = urlopen(str(sitenow))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)

urllib2.URLError:

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put "print sitenow" before urlopen and see what that prints out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the content of `sitenow`, but it looks like it is an invalid URL. Note that URLs use slashes and not backslashes (so the statement sould be something similar to `sitenow = site + "/" + product + "/" + str(u)`)